# TeamCity 5.x with xcodebuild?

Tags: xcode, macos, continuous-integration, teamcity, xcodebuild

We're considering migrating from CruiseControl/CruiseControl.NET to TeamCity.

A portion of our product is a Cocoa app, and I need to figure out if I want to try to migrate it to TeamCity as well, or if it would be better to leave it running under CruiseControl.

Everything I've found so far (including the teamcity-xcode plugin) refers to running xcodebuild under TeamCity 4.x, but we're running 5.x.

Is it possible to run an Xcode build under TeamCity 5.0?

What were your experiences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're currently looking into that as well, hence my googling bringing up this question. According to the [docs](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD5/Setting+up+and+Running+Additional+Build+Agents#SettingupandRunningAdditionalBuildAgents-UsingLaunchDaemonsStartupFilesonMacOSx) TeamCity can run agents on OSX and [this blog post](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2010/08/iphone/continuous-integration-for-iphone-projects-in-teamcity) discusses getting an iPhone build up and running. Hopefully these will prove a good starting point to getting an iOS build under TC.

Comment: We ended up using a Command Line step and running xcodebuild from that. we have also had success running GHUnit tests, etc. during our build from TC.